# Lines intersections distance on the asymptotes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Like in picture we have two lines. Lenght of one of them is 2E and other's lenght 2C and also ellipse  asymptotes are A and B and its center is on origin(0,0) I want to find D and F How can I calculate these lenghts?

[image: Ellipse Picture]

Comment: no they can be from 0 to A or B, C and E should determine F and D because we know A,B,C and E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are the [semi-axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes) AND
the point with coordinates $(x,y) = (C, E)$ lies on the ellipse,
which is given by
$$
\left( \frac{x}{A} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{B} \right)^2 = 1
$$
so
$$
\left( \frac{C}{A} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{E}{B} \right)^2 = 1
$$
holds, it is simply
$$
F = A - C = A - A \sqrt{1 - (E/B)^2} \\
D = B - E = B - B \sqrt{1 - (C/A)^2}
$$

Comment: D should depend just A ,B and C not E,  F should depend just A ,B and E not C. Because E and C lentgh dont depent each other.

Comment: sure? For instance if there wasnt line that intersects with A how could we calculate D just using A,B and C?!